# When I should use Flow, and when should I use Corountines?

Tags: android, database, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit

I've started to learning some more "advanced" stuff, and I'm a bit overwhelmed. I'm not sure, if I understand things correctly. I'd like to know, when I should use the Flow, and when Corountines.

Let's say that I have two apps. The first one have a few fragments within it. Every fragment will make different api call, for example:

- current forecast
- weekly forecast
- monthly forecast

api call will be done atleast once, since user can change data needed to perform an api call, for example - different city. Should I use corountines with this type of application?

The second application, will be based on database operations, let's say it'll be some kind of "journal", where user will be adding his meals, with some macronutrients. Since this application will be mostly about database, should I use Flow then?

What if I'll have an app, that store some data in database, but also performs the api calls? Should I "mix" flows (for database operations), and corountines (for api operations)?

Comment: Use a flow if you have a stream of values over time.  This isn't really different from "when would I use an Int and when would I use a List<Int>?". Flows and coroutines should be mixed all over the place, just like Ints and List<Int> are mixed all over the place.

Comment: Is there any reason you deleted your question from today? I spend a lot of time trying to help you with that. Doesn't feel good to have it completely deleted, without a word. And now it can't help anyone else either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to what Tenfour04 is saying, *coroutines* are about *concurrency* - they allow you to do multiple tasks *"at the same time"* instead of having a single task where each step can only take place when the step before has finished. That means you can start tasks that go off and take a while to produce a result, while the current task continues instead of having to wait for it (which is called *blocking*).

So when you're using a coroutine, you're able to do stuff that *"takes a while"*. There are two main patterns for this:

- things that return a single result, or no result at all
- things that return multiple results over time

The first includes coroutines created with `launch` (no result) or `async` (returns a value when completed), and also `suspend` functions which are just normal functions that have to be called from within a coroutine. They run, taking some time, and potentially return a value when finished.

The second, multiple results over time, is where *flow* comes in. This is something that emits values over time, and can terminate when it's finished, or stay active, potentially emitting values forever. You can think of it like a `List` or `Sequence`, but one where you can't access the elements on demand - they're *produced* by the flow as and when they're ready.

And this is why you have to collect them in the context of a coroutine - you can't block execution of your main code waiting for these items to be emitted, especially when collection can potentially never end! It's not just *"this might take some time to finish"* - it might never finish at all. That's why it needs to be done *concurrently* inside a coroutine task that can wait around for items, and *react* to them by doing something useful.

Lots of libraries in Android use `Flow` already - one example is *Room*, where database queries can return a `Flow` of items. What this means in practice is it will produce updates to that query over time, as the DB changes, so you have a data source you can collect from. Or you might just collect the first value and drop the flow entirely! But either way, you need to handle that collection within a coroutine.

---

As far as your specific question goes, your app architecture really depends on what you want to do. I think [this video by the Android team](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSB6_KE95bU) does a great job explaining how flows work as a data source, how you design around the reactive model, and how you divide your app into different layers and connect them with flows.

I'd really recommend [reading through the Kotlin coroutines guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-guide.html) before you look too closely at the Android side of things, just because that adds extra complications and things you need to be aware of (like lifecycles and the scopes associated with them). Once you have the general idea down, [here's another video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hNXFs1fYaY) (or an [older article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda)) explaining how to collect from flows in your lifecycle-aware components (usually Activities and Fragments). This is just about the end point though, the process of collection by the UI where you need to worry about if things are paused, stopped etc. Most of the time, you're just connecting things up normally, data sources to things that collect and process them and produce their own data, like the first video describes!

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean *suspend functions* rather than *coroutines*. Coroutines are used for Flows too...that's how you collect them.

Suspend functions are for fetching a piece of data once, imperatively. Flows are for passively receiving data repeatedly each time it is changed.

The difference is that with a reactive design (Flows), your input and output code is  completely independent from each other. When the user changes something, you inform the class that manages your data and it will take care of updating Flows "under the hood". You separately collect the Flows and use incoming data to update UI. These two pieces of code don't have to coordinate with each other.

With imperative design (suspend functions), your code for input and output is together in one place. When the user changes something, you call a suspend function to fetch data using the new input, and you take the returned data and connect it to UI.

I can't say more than that without straying into opinion. You can choose the type of design you prefer, or use a mixture.